nextjs - my hook does not re-render on value change
I use the following hook in a page.tsx file and then pass the data down to a table. When I click on a task, i have the following function
page.tsx
"use client"
const { allOpenTasks, getOpenTasks } = useTasks();
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTasks = async () => {
      await getOpenTasks(user.id);
    };
    fetchTasks();
  }, []);

useTasks.tsx
export const useTasks = () => {
  const [allOpenTasks, setAllOpenTasks] = useState<any>([]);

  const getOpenTasks = async (userId: any) => {
    try {
      const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from("task")
        .select(
          `
          id,
          is_complete
      `
        )
        .eq("owner_id", userId);

      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      if (data) {
        setAllOpenTasks(data);
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  const setTaskCompleted = function (taskId: any) {
    const updatedTasks = allOpenTasks.map((task: any) =>
      task.id === taskId ? { ...task, is_complete: !task.is_complete } : task
    );
    setAllOpenTasks([...updatedTasks]);
  };

  return {
    allOpenTasks,
    getOpenTasks,
    setTaskCompleted
  };
};

Table.tsx
"use client"
  const { setTaskCompleted } = useTasks();
  const clickCompleteTask = async (taskId: any) => {
    try {
      const { error } = await supabase
        .from("task")
        .update({
          is_complete: true,
        })
        .eq("id", taskId);
      if (error) throw new Error();
      setTaskCompleted(taskId);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

I have tried the following which works.
Instead of keeping the tasks state inside of the hook, i can maintain it in the page.tsx file and only use the hook to fetch the data from supabase.
I think it looks more clean if its inside the hook however it does not re-render on state change for a task object in page.tsx (when its set to completed)
I suspect its because when setTaskCompleted is initialized in the start, the allOpenTasks is empty since supabase hasn't set that yet.
If there is a better pattern i'd also be open to this.
Thanks!

have tried to wrap your getOpenTasks inside useEffect ? for example: useEffect(() => {// getOpenTasks code here}, [allOpenTasks]) ?

Why are you using useEffect and state to store all the data instead of having supabase and the server updating it for you, and having page.tsx as server component with async func?

@steve123 how would i optimistically update the UI then, wouldn't this result in a slight lag

could you try
const setTaskCompleted = function (taskId: any) {
  if (allOpenTasks.length > 0) {
    const updatedTasks = [...allOpenTasks].map((task: any) =>
      task.id === taskId ? { ...task, is_complete: !task.complete } : task
    );
    setAllOpenTasks(updatedTasks);
  } else {
    console.log("Tasks not loaded yet, cannot update completion status.");
  }
};

To address this and ensure a re-render when the data within allOpenTasks changes.
I think it have 2 problems,

if (allOpenTasks.length > 0) is data is empty if supabase return empty, ensure data is fetched before update i have condition for this.
[...allOpenTasks].map To address this and ensure a re-render when the data within allOpenTasks changes.

anyway, i think you code is perfect overall

It was actually how useHooks work. Importing useTasks in two different components led to two separate instances. Instead needed to pass setTaskCompleted down as a prop.
